# Pivot / Reshape pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Mock pandas dataframe to pivot:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['A','B','C'],
                   'year': [2012, 2014, 2016],
                   'val1': [1,2,3],
                   'val2': [5,6,7],
                   'val3': [9,10,11]})
```

I'd to pivot pandas dataframe to obtain following shape:

[image: pandas-pivot]

Fundamentally, what I am trying to do is have the year field as columns instead of row-value and retain the labels val1, val2, val3.

Comment: This does not make sense, in the original data frame, A has 3 values corresponding to `2012`, but after the change (I wouldn't call it pivot). A has only one value corresponding to `2012`. You fundamentally changed how data is related to each other.

Comment: @Psidom I see what you mean. Fundamentally, what I am trying to do is have the year field as columns instead of row-value and retain the labels val1, val2, val3.

Comment: You need to have a better example. You can have year as column, but it will look like this: `df.set_index(['id', 'year']).stack().unstack('year')` which is not what you expected.

Comment: When I run that on original dataframe, I get this error: `KeyError: 'Level Year not found'`, even though `Year` is a column in the dataframe.

Comment: `Year` or `year` ?

Comment: It's `Year`. That's not the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, It is just a quick and dirty way to do it. Not the best.

```
#Transpose Year and other columns
df1 = df[["year", "val1", "val2", "val3"]].T 

#Set first row as header
new_header = df1.iloc[0]
df1 = df1[1:]
df1.columns = new_header
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)

#concat back with id
df = pd.concat([df[["id"]],df1],axis=1).rename(columns={"index": "value"})
df
Out[259]: 
  id value  2012  2014  2016
0  A  val1     1     2     3
1  B  val2     5     6     7
2  C  val3     9    10    11
```

Comment: @kms do accept the solution if it helps. Thanks